# Cannot use WCF Endpoint in IOS App - WCF Working in Chrome

Tags: ios, wcf

Has anyone ever encountered an issue where a WCF service works fine when browsing to it within a browser but when using code like the code below it raises errors such as end point not found?

```
this.btnFetchData.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            WcfTestServiceClient client = new WcfTestServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://127.0.0.1:8086/WcfTestService.svc"));
            client.GetBookInfoCompleted += WcfTestServiceClient_GetBookInfoCompleted;
            client.GetBookInfoAsync ();
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
        };
```

I can the services address into any browser and it works fine.  Its just the code above that doesnt

I have also tried using the machine's actual IP Address rather than the standard 127.0.0.1 but I get other errors like bad host name

The WCF Service is being hosted by IIS (not IIS Express)

Paul

Comment: I don't see how this question relates to iOS.
Can you the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming:

- You are running Your service on Your machine.
- You are also running the browser on the same machine

The address you are using is the IP address of the local host of Your machine.

So when you Access from Your machine everything Works.

When you Access from the app then you are no longer on Your machine, so you cannot use localhost.

Comment: Thanks This was lots of fun! This was part of the issue but I also had to make a lot of config changes to parallels and my vm to allow host only network